# Aggregate $lookup stage overwrite data

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, lookup, aggregation

How I can make a lookup without to overwrite the existing data.

I recreated the situation in mopngodb playground: [mongo db playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0H_FjbWAvE0)

The problem is that I need to lookup the events and all the object ids (subevents, tags).

But the problem starts on the first lookup to the subevents. I need to have all the lookup data on the same place like the id for the lookup. But the rest from the data from the event is gone only the subevents are there.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

as you are giving lookup output name same as existing field it overwrites existing data, if you give new name it persists all data.

for example below aggregation gives the main events and sub events details, if required we can use project stages to put subevents under main event:

```
[{$match: {
  type: "EVENT"
}}, {$lookup: {
  from: "events",
  localField: "markedItemID",
  foreignField: "_id",
  as: "marked_event"
}}, {$unwind: {
  path: "$marked_event"
}}, {$lookup: {
  from: "events",
  localField: "marked_event.baseData.subEvents",
  foreignField: "_id",
  as: "marked_subEvents"
}}]
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/dlxqiK1PKdH